# How to detect the keyboard on the android window - Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: android, keyboard, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I need something to verify the existence of the keyboard in the window of an android app ... The problem is I can not test the focus / blur the input, and need that check for keyboard ... I see the official documentation Appcelerator and this functionality is only for iOS ... does anyone have a solution?

KeyboardVisible property for iOS:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App-property-keyboardVisible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iOS you can listen to the [keyboardframechanged](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App-event-keyboardframechanged) event. For Android, you might be able to use one of [these modules](http://gitt.io/search?q=keyboard%20type%3Amodule%20platforms%3Aandroid).

Answer (score 1):

[As you can see in the official docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Android-method-hideSoftKeyboard) there is no native way to detect if the keyboard is visible; if you need to show the keyboard when the user open the window, add a listener to 'open' and 'resume' (this one is from the activity, not the window, and is triggered also when your app go from the background to the foreground) for a function that focus your field, if you need to know when the keyboard is open to change the layout, android already try to fit it for you (in this case, place everything inside of a scrollview).

Answer (score -2):

There is no any direct way to do this. but some trick may be work. try this.

```
final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.activityRoot);
activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {
    int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
    if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
        ... do something here
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply friend, but I am using the Appcelerator Titanium (js) to build my app ... is not native ...